# Global Firebase Reference

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am having a bit of trouble getting a firebase key into a function for some reason.  I can log the correct key from the other functions on the page but not one of them, I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but right now I am super confused as to why. Could somebody explain this to me like I'm 5?

Code:

```
export class HomePage {

  infos = [];
  ref = firebase.database().ref('infos/').orderByChild('vote');


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router, public alertController: AlertController) {
    this.ref.on('value', resp => {
      this.infos = [];
      this.infos = snapshotToArray(resp);
    });
  }

  edit(key) {
    this.router.navigate(['/edit/'+key]);
console.log(key); <----- correct key here--
  }

  async delete(key) {
  console.log(key); <-------correct key here ---
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Confirm!',
      message: 'Are you sure want to delete this info?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('cancel');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            firebase.database().ref('infos/'+key).remove();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();

  }

  upvote(key) {
  console.log(key); <------Undefinded Key????---


};
```

When I try to return the key in the "Upvote" function it returns undefined, but everything else returns the correct key.  What am I missing here?

Edit:

```
<ion-button (click)="upvote(key)">Upvote</ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="downvote(key)">Downvote</ion-button>
```

Comment: Without seeing exactly how you're calling upvote, it's not really possible to tell.  Maybe you're passing it an undefined value.

Comment: I've added the html, Is that what you are referring to?